# When importing data from web page using Excel, hyperlinks are lost. How to solve this?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

When using the Data menu item in Excel to import data from web to spreadsheet, the hyperlinked items lose the link and appear just as text (for example try this: [Test](http://www.objectsbydesign.com/tools/umltools_byCompany.html) - How to overcome this?

Note:
I am trying to import the data table and use the link in the first column from my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose your table to import, select "options" in the upper right corner and deselect "Import  blocks into columns". Click OK then finish your import. This will import the table with its existing formatting, including the hyperlinks.

[image]

Comment: Please note that in Excel 2007 the dialog box for options is slightly different, and I had to select the "Full HTML formatting" to what you have suggested to make it work. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In MSexcel 2013, After clicking "Data" tab and "from web". Click on the upper right corner "Options" as CharlieRB said. In Web Query Options window that will be opened, 1. select Full HTML formatting and 2. deselect Import `<PRE>` blocks into columns as CharlieRB said.

Comment: It seems that these options are not available in the newer versions of Excel, but as a workaround one can import the webpage as `Text File` (using `Open file as` option in `Source` settings in Power Query Editor) and then locate and extract hyperlinks from the html data.